# How to load csv from url and display as listview flutter

Tags: flutter, csv, listview

I am new to flutter and I found load csv from local and display as listview but I want to load from url and display. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

A .csv from a remote source will probably have the content type of text/csv.

You should be able to call the url using a library (https://pub.dev/packages/http is a good choice, although I hear good things about Dio and probably a few others I haven't come across), get the data (e.g. as a http.Response), parse the response into some sort of model and then display it within the list view. Ideally the differences between displaying data from a local and remote source would be minimal - just where the data is coming from. This means you should be able to reuse the code you've written to load the data from a local source.

Without more information its hard to help. There's a good tutorial on building out Flutter apps using the Clean architecture at https://resocoder.com/category/tutorials/flutter/tdd-clean-architecture/. The difference will be that the Response data will be csv rather than JSON, so you'll need to sub in what you've done for the local loading.